# Set url to be used for assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a rails app

```
salmonfishing.com
```

which has a database. I have another app

```
salmonfishing-test.com
```

How can I alias the root url so that when a user goes to

```
http://salmonfishing-test.com
```

the assets and data from the

```
http://salmonfishing.com database
```

will be used.

My database.yml points to the 'salmonfishing' database, but the generated url for an image is

```
http://salmonfishing-test/bigfish.png
```

That is as would be expected, however internally I would like that to be aliased to

```
http://salmonfishing.com/bigfish.png
```

...basically so all assets and data are served from 'salmonfishing' database, and saved to it. Ran across various ways of setting sub-paths, but not root for assets and data.

Cheers,

```
 Jet
```

Comment: Two questions: Your assets are stored in the database, what kind? Are you speaking of app-related assets (like javascript, stylesheets and images for things like logos and UI) or user-related assets (like avatar images)?

Answer (score 0):

If your only problem is the wrong domain name in your asset URLs, you can change it in your environment config file: `config/environments/[whatever].rb`:

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://salmonfishing.com"
```

This line is already present in `production.rb`, but it's commented out.